# Drawing an arc on an image inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to clip and display a very large image inside a `canvas` div.

Using basic calculations and `drawImage` I managed to clip the image around the pixel I want and display the clipped image.

[An example is here on JSFiddle (displaying image arround eye of the person)](http://jsfiddle.net/9k4LV/1/)

I would like to add an arc which will be over the image around the pixel (the `sx, sy` pixel I use in the example in `drawImage`), how should I adjust the coordinates ?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('test-canvas');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 285;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function () {
    //context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 1324 - 250, 1228 - 142.5, 500, 285, 0, 0, 500, 285);
};


imageObj.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b3/Edvard_Munch_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arc is part of a path, which can be either *filled* or *stroke*. In order to get your desired result, you need to move to a point on your circle*, create the arc, and then use `stroke()` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9k4LV/2/)):

```
function strokeCircle(ctx, midx, midy, radius){
    ctx.moveTo(midx + radius, midy);
    ctx.arc(midx, midy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}

imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 1324 - 250, 1228 - 142.5, 500, 285, 0, 0, 500, 285);
    strokeCircle(context, 250, 142.5, 30);
};
```

<sub>* The correct coordinate depends on your polar coordinates used for the circle. If you draw from 0 to `Math.PI`, you need to start on the right-most point.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, can you change the strokeCircle `ctx` to `context` please